# how to restrict setting a property of innerclass just from the outer class in c#

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes, outer-classes

I have the nub of the code like this:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public static InnerClass GetInnerClass()
    {
        return new InnerClass() { MyProperty = 1 };
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what is the solution to property named `MyProperty` just be settable from the `InnerClass` and the `OuterClass`, and out of these scopes, `MyProperty` just be readonly

Comment: Do you *have* to be able to set it after construction at all? Can you not just make it a constructor parameter and have a read-only property?

Comment: You can approach this with `internal`, with the classes in a separate assembly. But you really shouldn't' be wanting to.

Comment: I'm curious as to a real-world non-contrived example for the need for this.  It certainly seems like a convenient feature to have, but I suspect that the relationship between `OuterClass` and `InnerClass` may be calling for a different structure than what's being attempted here.

Comment: @JonSkeet: i can not make it a constructor parameter

Comment: @Henk Holterman: i can not set it as `internal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no protection level for that. `internal` is the tightest you can use, which is limited to files in the same assembly. If you cannot make it a constructor parameter as has been proposed, you could use an interface:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public static InnerClass GetInnerClass()
    {
        return new InnerClassImpl() { MyProperty = 1 };
    }

    public interface InnerClass
    {
        int MyProperty { get; }
    }
    private class InnerClassImpl : InnerClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `InnerClassImpl` should not implement `MyProperty` from interface as only getter ?

Comment: @am1r_5h: It implements a getter, so that satisfies the interface.  The setter is implementation-specific and is only seen by `OuterClass` in this case.  (Which is necessary to set the value in the object initializer.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no access modifier which allows that. You can create `IInnerClass` interface and make the property readonly within interface declaration:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public static IInnerClass GetInnerClass()
    {
        return new InnerClass() { MyProperty = 1 };
    }

    public interface IInnerClass
    {
        int MyProperty { get; }
    }

    private class InnerClass : IInnerClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```